# Uploading a folder which may contain sub folders along with files

Tags: php, asp.net, apache-flex, file-upload, filesystems

I'm working on an application where client may upload any folder which may contain sub folders along with files. Is it possible to upload a folder instead of a file? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be getting a list of files within these folders to handle in your upload. You can keep track of the directory structure and rebuild it within the server's user directory.

Comment: @Atticus- That is ok but how can I upload a folder instead of a file. I'm not getting. If you know any logic/link, please share it. Thank you.

Comment: I'm pretty sure uploading a 'folder' is just a list of files along with the name of a folder which will be created when the files are added on the server..

Comment: Unless some additional technique is used (JavaApplet, maybe Flash) it is not possible to upload a complete directory through http.

Comment: ^^ exactly, i'm pretty sure it's a list of files with some meta data on the directory paths of the files to reconstruct it similarly server side